# Rock, Paper, Scissors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a project in [`CodeCademy`](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/0/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)

First I had this problem that it was always displaying scissors with some random numbers no matter what I type in the prompt, now the problem is in the syntax, it's just not working.

**Here is the code:**

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if(computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if(0.34 < computerChoice <= 0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";

}
else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";

}
console.log(computerChoice);
```

So where is the problem in my code ?

Comment: You don't even use what the prompt function returns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that say "it's just not working" without providing any more detail aren't received well. Please describe what your code is trying to do (specifically the code that's failing), and what error you get, or how what it produces differs from what you expected. See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: At least one issue is `0.34 < computerChoice <= 0.66` needs to be something like `0.34 < computerChoice && computerChoice <= 0.66`

Comment: @Michael Petrotta "TypeError: string is not a function"

Comment: @Michael Petrotta What ? Asking a simple question is a bad behavior here ?

Comment: "Questions that say "it's just not working" without providing any more detail aren't received well. Please describe what your code is trying to do (specifically the code that's failing), and what error you get, or how what it produces differs from what you expected."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above that you should provide some more detail on how you are trying to solve the problem. But one immediate thing that comes to mind is:

```
if(computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if(computerChoice <= 0.66){
    computerChoice = "paper";

}
else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";

}
```

In the 2nd if conditional, you don't need to check if the computerChoice is greater than .34, since it has to be in order to pass by the logic of `computerChoice <= 0.33`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried this way before the one I wrote in the question , it's also not working .

Comment: Okay - please be more specific about what is not working. After making the change, I can run the code and find the results of `console.log(computerChoice)` do represent all 3 choices. One possible mistake you are making is console.logging `computerChoice` again without running the whole code again. Once `computerChoice` is set in memory, it will not change by console.logging. The variation comes from invoking Math.random(). Without that step, you will keep getting the same answer.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. If you cannot get it to work, please post a description of what is not working.

Comment: OK so I removed console.log and it worked and with all 3 variations (rock,paper and scissors) , but Isn't that wrong Just writing the code without console.logging the variable ? Also Is it wrong that they are displaying in quotes ?

Comment: @user3738507, after reading your last comment, I don't think I'm answering the question you are asking. Can you please describe the expected output you are looking for?